# Google Maps Directions APIv3 with custom Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map which calculates a route from point A to point B using the standard [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) with google maps. On this Map I have custom markers which I obtain from a [database](http://secure.transcommercial.co.za/API/Toll). I want to know which of these markers intersect with the selected route.

I have created a fiddle with all the necessary code segments, but the map does not seem to generate in JSFiddle :(

http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/94kLnrr7/2/
Here is my JavaScript to generate the map and add the markers

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var lati = -33.9149861;
var longi = 18.6560594;
var markers;

function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: chicago
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    markers = $.getJSON("http://secure.transcommercial.co.za/API/Toll", function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ko.toJS(data).length; i++) {
            new google.maps.Marker({
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(ko.toJS(data)[i].TollLatitude, ko.toJS(data)[i].TollLongitude),
                map: map,
                icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"
            });
        }
    });

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        });
    }
}

function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: @geocodezip I am using http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html in my ASP MVC application. All the ko.toJS does is converts the object from my API to a usable format, in this case float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you set `markers` to the return of `$.getJSON`this will not have any result, you must store the markers on your own :

   ```
    //let markers be an array
    var markers=[];

    //..........

    //requesting the data
    $.getJSON("http://secure.transcommercial.co.za/API/Toll", function (data) {
       data=ko.toJS(data);
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       //push the new marker onto the markers-array
       markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
           animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].TollLatitude, data[i].TollLongitude),
           map: map,
           icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"
       }));
     }
    });
   ```

To check if a marker is placed on a route use the method [`google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) .

It expects as arguments a `LatLng` (marker-position) and a `Polyline`(create the line on the fly based on the `overview`_path of the returned route, the line must not be visible)

Example(hides all markers except the markers that are placed on the given route):

```
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            //create Polyline based on route 
            var line=new google.maps.Polyline({path:response.routes[0].overview_path});
            markers.forEach(function(marker){
             marker.setMap((google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(marker.getPosition(),line,.01))?map:null);
            });
        }
    });
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/srycht1z/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/srycht1z/)

Related to jsfiddle: you must choose the option "no wrap, in head". Currently you use the option "onload", so the entire code will be executed when `window.onload` fires. But when you execute the code at this time, initialize will never be called, because it also will be called at the onload-event, which already has been fired when you add the listener and will not fire again.